# How to find ASP.Net Core version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, version

I'm using WebsitePanel and in Web Sites ==> Extensions tab, the ASP.NET version is 4 integrated pipeline.

My question is that how can I figure out what version of .Net Core is my server using now?

I don't really know if the asp.net is 4, the .Net Core is also 4 or not. And if it's version 4, then does it mean that version 2 is installed? Because in extensions tab, I have four options: 2, 2 integrated pipeline, 4 and 4 integrated pipeline.

Comment: There is no .net core 4 at the moment, yet.

Comment: Then how to know which version is installed?

Comment: If websitepanel is all you get, you cannot see that info.

Comment: Then thank you both.

Comment: In Linux servers there we can see php version by phpinfo file, there's no such a thing in windows servers to see iis/core/etc versions and info?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To check which .NET Core Version is installed you can run one of the following commands on the command prompt.

```
dotnet --version      // Display .NET Core SDK version.

dotnet --info          //Display .NET Core information.

dotnet --list-runtimes   // Display the installed runtimes.

dotnet --list-sdks       // Display the installed SDKs.
```

Also, you can view all .NET Core versions Installed on the system by navigating to the installation folder on the below path.

```
%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\sdk
```

**Update:** Form .NET 6 and later versions we can use the below command to lists the latest available version of the .NET SDK and .NET Runtime and will show also whether your installed versions are up-to-date or out of support.

```
dotnet sdk check
```

Comment: How can I check the version of the .NET Core used in an opened in VS solution?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha In Solution Explorer, open the right-click menu for the project that you want to check, and choose Properties, then select Application tab > Target framework

Comment: That helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
dotnet --info
```

The above command at your terminal will provide all the info

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the visual studio ide whether 2017, 2019, 2022 or any other version all you need to do is go to the solution explorer, and click on the properties. It will display the version of framework you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Yahgozie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70541994/7191056)'s answer this is a [screen shot](https://i.imgur.com/Oq007At.jpg) of how to access your project's properties... Note that you can change your **target framework**... if for example your are getting a *conflict* with a NuGet package, say `Microsoft Entity Framework Core`...